# Flex 4 Easy Way To Transition Between States

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, transition

Is there an easy way, using only MXML, to transition between states that add and remove elements.

For example:

```
<s:Group includeIn="state1"/>
<s:Group includeIn="state2"/>
```

Can MXML transitions slide state1 out and state2 in, for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on using transitions with states: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fab.html ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the link posted above here's a way to apply a single transition to multiple targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:views="views.*"  >

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="home"/>
        <s:State name="help"/>
        <s:State name="instructions"/>
        <s:State name="settings"/>
        <s:State name="feedback"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="*" >
            <s:Sequence >
                <s:Wipe direction="right" duration="350" target="{this}"/>
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

    <views:Home         id="home"       includeIn="home"            width="100%" height="100%" ownerComponent="{this}"/>
    <views:Help         id="help"       includeIn="help"            width="100%" height="100%" ownerComponent="{this}" />
    <views:Instructions id="instructions"   includeIn="instructions"    width="100%" height="100%" ownerComponent="{this}" />
    <views:Settings     id="settings"   includeIn="settings"        width="100%" height="100%" ownerComponent="{this}" />
    <views:Feedback     id="feedback"   includeIn="feedback"        width="100%" height="100%" ownerComponent="{this}" />

</s:Group>
```

The previous transition creates a wipe from one direction to the other.

The next transition fades from one view to another:

```
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="home" >
        <s:Sequence >
            <s:Fade target="{this}" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0"/>
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{[home,help,instructions,settings,feedback]}"/>
            <s:AddAction target="{home}"/>
            <s:Fade target="{this}" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1"/>
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

The next slides one view in while sliding the rest out:

```
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="home" >
        <s:Sequence duration="1000" >
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Move applyChangesPostLayout="true" targets="{notHomeTargets}" xFrom="0" xTo="{-width}"/>
                <s:AddAction target="{home}" />
                <s:Move applyChangesPostLayout="true" target="{home}" xFrom="{width}" xTo="0"/>
            </s:Parallel>
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{targets}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

You would have to create one for each state with the last examples.